# Can static analysis detect memory leaks?

Tags: testing, memory-leaks, code-analysis, static-analysis

Having received my ISTQB certification a long time ago, I remember that it makes the following distinction:
-static analysis: performed on the source code, detects unreachable code, unassigned values etc.
-dynamic analysis: can detect memory leaks etc., requires execution (profiling).

But when I search today, I can see various sites and sources mentioning static analysis is capable of detecting memory leaks too.

So I wonder, is static analysis really capable of that? And if so, what is the different between dynamic analysis then, in terms of results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A well designed/implemented static analysis tool can detect many cases where some code *must* have a leak, merely by analyzing the code. Tools like Coverity/Prevent do this pretty well.

Such tools can also detect many cases where there *might* be a leak (and the Turing tarpit prevents it from knowing for sure). There is a huge argument about whether the tool should report these, because they might be false positives, and false positives are a waste of programmer time.  [Worse: if a programmer wastes her time on several false positives, s/he often quits using the tool altogether, and now even the value of truly detected bugs are lost].

Dynamic analysis tools can usually tell if a leak happens, at the moment it happens at runtime.  (Imagine a pointer to heap being held in a local variable, and that local variable going out of scope).  (See our [CheckPointer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/) tool for a dynamic analysis tool that can detect virtually every stack/heap allocation/pointer misuse error encountered at runtime).

Answer (score 14):

Being one of the developers of a static analyzer, I can state that the problem of searching for memory leaks is an extremely complicated and sometimes impossible task for SCA. Static analyzers are really weak in this sphere, and we shouldn't expect much from them. Dynamic analyzers are much stronger regarding the search of memory leaks and if there is a task to find them, then you should consider dynamic, not static analysis.

Yes, static analyzers are able to find simple cases of memory leaks. But in practice you have the memory leaks mostly when the code is complicated and the memory is free/allocated in different parts of the program. Therefore, static analysis is really not very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure a static analyzer could catch:

```
void MyFunction()
{
    char * leakable = new char[1000];
}
```

so, the answer to your question is self evidently "Yes".

A more interesting question is can it catch more subtle leaks.   And the answer there is "often yes" if it has access to all the source code involved or a representation of the `contract` for the methods involved (i.e.: If the comment says: The caller is responsible for releasing the returned object", then the static analyzer may not catch, it, but if that same concept is expressed in code (or can be arrived at by analyzing the code), a static analyzer can find the problem -- sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Static analysis is capable of detecting the potential for a memory leak, in the form of a construct that is can be anticipated to lead to memory leaks.  It cannot, however, detect the presence of an actual memory leak at runtime since it never examines the execution of the codebase.

Comment: -1 Sure it can.   Your porgram contains "malloc(1276)", and that pointer is never used.   That's a leak.  A static analysis tool can see many such cases.  What a static analysis tool cannot do is detect *all* memory leaks.